# Redirect Loop when trying to return a new mysqli object

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to implement a simple login system:

```
function parseConfigData(&$data)
{
    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode(file_get_contents("data.config"), TRUE)), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) 
    {
        $data[$key] = $val;
    }
}

function dbcon()
{
    $data = array();
    parseConfigData($data);
    print_r($data);
    return new mysqli($data['server'], $data['user'], $data['pass'], $data['db']);
}

function signin()
{
    $con = dbcon();
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT id,code,role FROM users WHERE user=? AND pass=?");
    $query->bind_param("ss", $_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($id, $code, $role);
    $query->fetch();
    if($id == null)
    {
        redirect("index.php?fail");
        return;
    }
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['code'] = $code;
    $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
    $con->close();
    //redirect("dashboard.php");
}
```

For some reason this gives me the "This webpage has a redirect loop" error under chrome.
If I comment out the `return new mysqli ...` line, I don't get the redirect loop anymore.
I can't wrap my head around what could be possibly causing this. Help?

Comment: I suspect the `mysqli` observation is a red herring, and that if you turn on `error_reporting()` or check your error logs, you'll see an error on the second line of `signin()`. I suspect that whatever is calling `signin()` is causing the redirect loop.